Formik Form Resets Unexpectedly on iPhone Chrome Browser
I'm experiencing an issue with a Formik form in my React application. When I submit the form using Formik on an iPhone's Chrome browser, the form resets automatically without any explicit call to resetForm. This behavior is inconsistent, as it does not occur on other browsers or on desktop devices.
Details:

Frameworks/Libraries: React, Formik
Browser: Chrome on iPhone
Expected Behavior: After form submission, the form should not reset unless resetForm is called explicitly.
Actual Behavior: The form resets immediately upon submission without calling resetForm.

Code Snippet:
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';

const MyForm = () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ name: '' }}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        console.log('Form values:', values);
        // No resetForm call here
      }}
    >
      {({ isSubmitting }) => (
        <Form>
          <Field type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
          <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default MyForm;

Steps to Reproduce:

Open the application on an iPhone's Chrome browser.
Fill out the form field.
Submit the form.
Observe that the form resets automatically without any explicit resetForm call.

Troubleshooting Attempts:

Ensured no resetForm call is present in the submit handler.
Checked for any form reset side effects but found none.
Verified the issue is specific to iPhone Chrome browser, as it works correctly on other browsers and desktop devices.

Questions:

Has anyone encountered similar behavior with Formik on iPhone's Chrome browser?
Are there any known issues or workarounds for this specific browser/device combination?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

i test your code and did'nt found any problem in your code
even i test it your code in iphone chrome and it runs well
you can use this code instead
event.preventDefault();
